# Change the shape of a list and add it to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a query that returns a series of values, let's call it answers. This is a list of values, when I print it out. It shows me this
['0     1\n1     1\n2     0\n3     1\n4     0\n     ..\n70    0\n71    0\n72    1\n73    0\n74    0\nLength: 75, dtype: int64']

It says that the length is 75 here. but if I use len() to assess its length, it says it is 1. I am confused here. I want to attach this list with 75 values to a dataframe that has 75 rows, but if I just do df['Values']=answers, it shows that there is a length difference and it cannot be done. Can someone help me what is wrong here?Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your list is: ['0 1\n1 1\n2 0\n3 1\n4 0\n ..\n70 0\n71 0\n72 1\n73 0\n74 0\nLength: 75, dtype: int64'] There might be an error, since you do not need '\n'.

-First: try to put only the values. Example: [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, and so on]

-Second: I sow that there is this ['0 1\n1 1\n2 0\n3 1\n4 0\n ..\n70 0\n71 0\n72 1\n73 0\n74 0\nLength: 75, dtype: int64'] single quotes '' that encompass everything, and when using len(your_list), it'll return that its length it's 1. So take it out.

- So, at the end of all, your list should look like this: [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, ...] (without no single quotes)
- If it still didn't work, I can help you, but it would be better to see the whole context of your coding problem. For example, your list may be wrong because of the way you created it, since working with loops (that looks like the case) can cause some trouble.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the single quote problem. That makes so much sense. I also went back to check my program and figured out what was wrong with the \n, it shouldn't be there. But the hints were super helpful. Appreciated!